# Assert if value is present in any position of json array using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a json array such as the one below:

```
{
   "employees":[
      {
         "name":"Shyam",
         "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com"
      },
      {
         "name":"Bob",
         "email":"bob32@gmail.com"
      },
      {
         "name":"Jai",
         "email":"jai87@gmail.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I am certain that the value 'Bob' would come at a certain position for example position 2, I can assert using :
`assert json.loads(data)["employees"][2] == "Bob"`

But, in my case, the value 'Bob' could be in any position of the array . In such case, how can I assert if the key 'name' and value 'Bob' are present in any position of the json array

Comment: Once `json.loads` returns, you are dealing with a Python data structure; `json` is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use loop over the `employees` within `any` to perform this check.

```
contents = json.loads(data)
assert any(i['name'] == 'Bob' for i in contents['employees'])
```